# $A$ be a nonzero finite abelian group then $A$ is not a projective or injective $\Bbb Z$ module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

To prove that if $A$ be a nonzero finite abelian group then $A$ is not a projective or injective $\Bbb Z$ module.

Ref: Dummit Foote Sec 10.5 Q7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hints:**

A finitely generated projective module over a P.I.D. is free.

An injective module over an integral domain is divisible.

A non-zero finite abelian group is neither free (it has torsion) nor divisible (it has an annihilator) over  $\mathbf Z$.

Answer (score 6):

A nonzero finite abelian group is a direct sum of prime power order cyclic groups. If $p$ is prime and $n>0$, then the (canonical) short exact sequence
$$
0\to p^n\mathbb{Z}/p^{2n}\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p^{2n}\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}\to0
$$
is not split. Note that the first and last term are isomorphic. This proves that $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ is neither projective nor injective. A direct summand of a projective (resp. injective) module is projective (resp. injective).

Comment: Refer to Dummit and Foote (3rd edition) 10.5.3 and 10.5.4 respectively for the last statement and see 5.2 of Dummit and Foote page 161 theorem 5 for the used theorem. very elegant argument.