# class of abelian groups

Tags: modules, abelian-groups, direct-sum, finitely-generated, torsion-groups

What class of abelian gropus $\cal K$ is this a very natural one:

the members of $\cal K$ are of the following form:

the direct sum $\oplus$ of finitely many $\mathbb Z_n$' s
and finitely many $\mathbb Q$ ?

How this $\cal K$ is called ?

I believe that these are either projective or injective $\mathbb Z-$modules, but I'm not sure.

**EDIT:** are these $\mathbb Z-$modules actually **all** $\mathbb Z-$modules ?

Comment: With $\mathbb{Z}_n,$ I assume you mean the integers modulo $n$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Is that correct?

Comment: @DouglasMolin Yes, right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A $\mathbb{Z}$-module is the same thing as an abelian group.  The class $\mathcal{K}$ that you've described certainly doesn't contain all of the abelian groups (for instance, it doesn't contain $\mathbb{Z}$), so the answer to the question from the edit is "no".

Assuming that your $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the integers mod $n$, then $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is neither projective nor injective as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module ([$A$ be a nonzero finite abelian group then $A$ is not a projective or injective $\Bbb Z$ module.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528397/a-be-a-nonzero-finite-abelian-group-then-a-is-not-a-projective-or-injective)).

I don't know if $\mathcal{K}$ has a standard name - perhaps someone else can address that part of the question.