# Why a nonzero finite abelian group is not projective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence, projective-module, free-modules

Here is the question I am trying to solve (I know it is answered here [$A$ be a nonzero finite abelian group then $A$ is not a projective or injective $\Bbb Z$ module.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528397/a-be-a-nonzero-finite-abelian-group-then-a-is-not-a-projective-or-injective) but the answer is not very clear to me, so I am trying to write every detail in my solution below and ask for clarification of steps that I do not know how to prove):

Let $A$ be a nonzero finite abelian group.

$(a)$ Prove that $A$ is not a projective $\mathbb Z$-module.

**My thoughts:**

Since $A$ is a nonzero finite abelian group, then by the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, we know that $A \cong \mathbb Z^r \times \mathbb Z_{n_1} \times \mathbb Z_{n_2} \times \dots \times \mathbb Z_{n_s}$ with $r \geq 0$ and $n_j \geq 2$ for all $j$ and $n_{i+1}|n_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq s-1.$

But then I want to use the following definition of a projective module to negate that $A$ is projective:

If $P$ is a quotient of the $R$-module $M$ then $P$ is isomorphic to a direct summand of $M,$ i.e., every short exact sequence $$ 0 \to L \to M \to P \to 0 $$ splits.

Where $L$ is an $R$-module.

I am wondering why there is a surjection $\pi: \mathbb Z^r  \to A$ and why if $\mathbb Z^r$ does not have torsion elements this map cannot split? What exactly the exact sequence that we are using?

Can explain this in detail to me please?

Comment: If $f\colon A\to B$ is a group homomorphism, and $a\in A$ has order $n$, then $f(a)$has order dividing $n$. In particular, if $B$ has no nontrivial elements of finite order, then $f(a)$ is the identity of $B$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin but our group $A$ can have the power of $\mathbb Z$ be zero

Comment: Invoking the structure theorem is unnecessary. If $A$ is finite, then every element of $A$ has finite order. The only element of $\mathbb{Z}^r$ of finite order is $(0,0,\ldots,0)$.

Comment: (You are using $r$ twice, for different things...)

Comment: but A is not necessarily finite

Comment: what do you mean by your last comment? You meant that the map $\pi$ must be from $\mathbb Z^n$ for example?

Comment: Oh I see your point .... You are saying that $\mathbb Z^r$ is always finite .... right? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: I am not sure how is your first comment answering my questions ..... Could you please explain more?

Comment: "You are saying that $\mathbb{Z}^r$ is always finite". Why would I say such a mind-bogglingly false and silly thing? My first comment completely answers your question, and you need to do some work on your own. I will not pre-chew it for you so you can just swallow the pap. So while I could "explain more", I will not do so.

Comment: "But $A$ is not necessarily finite." Really? Then why, oh why do you state "Let $A$ be a nonzero ***finite*** abelian group"? Did you even read what you wrote?

Comment: sorry about that, I was thinking about the Fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups

Comment: that is why you said "Invoking the structure theorem is unnecessary" , but I invoked it because I wanted a reason for saying that $A$ is torsion and I did not find any other way of justifying this. Do you have any other way of justifying this@ArturoMagidin

Comment: Finite means torsion by Lagrange's theorem. Why is that not **blatantly** obvious? Do you not know what "torsion" means?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes I know

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is finite there is a surjective homomorphism $\mathbb Z^n \to A$ where $n$ is the order of $A$ for example (map each generator to each element of $A$).  If $A$ is projective, then $A$ must be a subgroup of $\mathbb Z^n$, but since $nA = 0$ by Lagrange, this is impossible.

Answer (score -1):

First, note that since $A$ is finite $r=0$.

Second, Consider the map $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A:1\rightarrow (1,1,\ldots,1)$. This map is surjective so you can build an exact sequence out of it, but $f$ does not split and you reach a contradiction.

Comment: How can I build an exact sequence out of this map?

Comment: why this sequence will not split? Do you have z proof for this? Can you add this details to your answer please?

Comment: The map is not surjective in general, since the image is cyclic but $A$ need not be cyclic. The map you have defined is surjective if and only if $A$ is cyclic. This is just wrong.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right